# Is there a way to cast a ray at Java graphics shapes?

Tags: java, fonts, graphics, shapes, raytracing

So I have a strange question, I'm working on a simple/toy raytracer as a side project. I'm using Java's Graphics2D library to render text. Currently this is done by rendering the text to a BufferedImage, then using that as a texture map to clip ray intersections. This creates a floating 2d text in my 3D world.

I want to make a 3D text primitive as well. I'd like to avoid modelling each character myself and reinventing the wheel for layout. My idea is to use the Font and TextLayout from the Java libraries to get shapes. As far as I can tell there is no way to get a 2D raycast to the shapes with Java's API. Is there an easy way to do a raycast on Java shapes?

From what I can tell the only way to do it will be to use getOutline() of GlyphVector to get a Shape, then use the PathIterator to get the line segments and parabola segments to raycast against. Am I missing a better way to do this? Would I be better off just modelling a font and laying it out myself?

Comment: by "3D text primitive" do you mean something like taking the text and extruding it to form 3d shapes or just to render it without rasterizing it first?

Comment: I do mean extrusion. However if I project my Ray onto a 2d plane, my intersection text will essentially work for an infinitely extruded text, then we use the ray equation to find out if the intersection happened at an appropriate third coordinate. The cap faces are a special case. Rather the same way an infinite cylinder can be intersected with a plane projected Ray and circle.